# How to delete blocks in vim using search and delete option

Tags: vim

I need to delete blocks start with code. code will have the following format.

```
code {
..
  {..}
  {..}
..
}
```

If I do `:g/code.*/.,/}/d`, it is only deleting up to the first closing curly bracket. But I need the entire code block to be deleted.

There are thousands of this code block in my file and also each having random numbers of curly bracket sets inside it(In the example, I have given only 2 sets of curly brackets inside code. actually it will vary code to code).

So, basically I am looking for one command which will search `code { .* }` in my file and deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one relatively straightforward way to do it:

```
:g/^code/normal! $dV%
```

where…

1. on each line starting with `code` (`:g/^code`),
2. we move to the end of the line, on the opening brace (`/normal! $`),
3. we delete from here to the matching brace while forcing the motion to be linewise (`dV%`).

The keys, here, are:

- `:help %`, which is a motion that covers the text from the brace under the cursor to the other brace. This is an inclusive motion, meaning that the text covered includes the original cursor position and the target, and it is characterwise, meaning that operations are restricted to the text covered by the motion.

  Doing `d%` would delete the braces and their content, but not the `code`  on the first line.
- `:help forced-motion`, which allows us to force the characterwise operation above into a linewise operation by prepending the original motion, `%`, with a `V`.

Comment: Thanks romainl. It works. But in my file, the last character of each line that starts with "code" is space not {. So How can I change your command for this scenario? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a trailing space after the opening `{`? If so, the command to put after `:normal!` would be `f{cV%`. See `:help f`.

Comment: Ooops: `f{dV%`.

Comment: ya I Understood.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with a macro? Press this: `qa/code.*^MV%dk`, where `^M` is you pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>; then hit <kbd>@</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd>. For more details, search the web for "vim macros".